# HTML5 Boilerplate plugins.js question

Tags: jquery, html, boilerplate

Can someone explain to me how they use the plugins.js file,
found in HTML5 Boilerplate. I don't really understand the purpose
of it, or how it can be useful.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a [Getting Started guide](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/wiki/Get-Started!) to help out with that. Let me know if it is not clear!

Comment: appears to be gone (repo has moved but it's not on the new repo's wiki)

Answer (score 5):

Paul Irish (the author of boilerplate) has made a "official guide" for it, it's hosted on the net.tuts+ network.

[Link here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-official-guide-to-html5-boilerplate/)

Answer (score 2):

It's used to add your own jQuery snippets and code inside

```
(function($){

})(window.jQuery);
```

Or any custom javascript outside it.
They added an option to log and debug your js inside (read the comments inside the file)